# How to read two strings from the same line in Pascal?

Tags: string, line, pascal

I'm trying to read two string variables from the same line in pascal.
The two strings are separated by empty space.

I've tried reading it like one string, then separating it on two parts, but then I have a problem because the string is bigger than 255 characters.

Here is the string I'm trying to read:

> kyGOwpLobZvGynmdpiujxhUwphFsTTipuyAwpeffcckLuPouxmpQwGeMxqDoIqeWVkpdLueirlLiabfhxjnwbyMDYUfhGmlnFJdmfhtxljPqicbotSBvkKaQdsmbyrhmmSdexHjwdnecjRtzef mkhRyGOwpLobZvGynmdpiujxhUwphFsTTipuyAwpeffcckLumWbnbfdhlzFmnkkrwNsewPouxmpQwGeMxqDoIqeWVkpdLueirlLiabfhxjnwbyMDYUfhGmlnFJdmfhtxljPqicbotSBvkKaQdsmbyrhmmSdexHjwdnecjRtzeajfz`

The line is not always the same length, and the empty space is not on the same location.

I'm trying to figure out if by deleting some characters from the second string you can get the first one.

Example: STRING aSgasTsaRoIgfNfdsG
should result a positive answer.

Here is the code that checks for that.

```
q:=1;  
for m:=1 to length(b) do  
begin  
if b[m] = a[q] then  
q:=q+1;
end;

q:=q-1;

writeln(q);

if q = length(a) then  
writeln('YES')  
else  
writeln('NO');
```

where a is the first string, b is the second one.

I'm reading the first big string as one variable and then cut it in two parts.
The problem occurs when the first string is bigger than 255 characters. That's why I want to know how I can read two strings from the same line.

The code I'm using to separate the strings:

```
readln(x);  

x:=LONGSTRINGHERE;  
blank:=' ';
Location := Pos(blank, x);  

a:=Copy(x, 1, (Location-1));  

b:=Copy(x, (Location+1), length(x));
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. How long is the line of text? Where are you getting it from? Is the space always at the same place (for instance, the *x* character)? Can you post the code you've tried so far that isn't working? Pasting a long string and a very brief description of the problem doesn't give much to go on, and it is preferred here that you show some effort to solve the problem yourself first. Can you please edit your question and provide some additional information? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `readln()` to read the entire line perhaps you could use `read()` with a variable of type `char` to read one character at a time into your first string until you detect a space and then read the second string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use freepascal compiler and replace string by ansistring which can be up to 2^16 = 65536 characters.